# How can I check if redirected from Google in firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm now building an EC platform, integrating firebase authentication service.
But I have a problem.
I've used redirected method like following.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

And I can get authentication result in the client side(browser) using firebase api, like this.

```
firebase.auth()
  .getRedirectResult()
  .then((result) => {
    if (result.credential) {
      ...
    }
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
  })
```

But I want to check in **Server Side**  not in the browser, if the request was redirected from the Social OAuth Platform or else.

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] does not work, so I thought we can set redirect uri as a custom parameter, and check the uri in server side but [`setCustomParameters`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#setcustomparameters) does not support redirect_uri. Is there any other api to set redirect_uri?